# Count specific value across different columns in a row

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has the below columns:

```
 - request_id (Auto increment)
    - is_requested_data1 - (Enum (y,n)
    - is_requested_data2 - (Enum (y,n)
    - is_requested_data3 - (Enum (y,n)
    - is_requested_data4 - (Enum (y,n)
```

For a specific row , lets say request_id = 1 , i want to know the count of 'y'.
I have tried declaring a variable and tried to increment the value of the variable everytime there is a 'y' for any column using mysql cases but it doesn't seem to work .

Please advice .

Comment: count of `y` from which column?

Comment: all the columns have the datatype set to ENUM - y or n . So 'y' can be the value for any column . If there are 3 'y's for request_data1,request_data2 and request_data3 , what will be the query to get the count as '3'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `COUNT` but `+`.

```
SELECT
    request_id,
    (
        (is_requested_data1 = 'y') + 
        (is_requested_data2 = 'y') + 
        (is_requested_data3 = 'y') + 
        (is_requested_data4 = 'y')
    ) AS totalYs
FROM 
    your_table
WHERE request_id = 1
```

**Note:** Since MySQL boolean expression resolves into `0/1`. So that whenever a column matches to `y` it returns 1 otherwise 0.

So, if `is_requested_data1` is equal to `y` then the following returns 1

```
is_requested_data1 = 'y' returns 1
```

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8ee78/1/0)</kbd>  <sub>For convenience I've used the column names `A, B, C, D`.</sub>

Comment: thanks but the above isnt what i want.  If there are 3 y's as mentioned above. I want the output as '3' . I just want to know how many y's are there for any request_id .

Comment: In fact it counts the number of `y`s for a given `request_id`. That's what you wanted. If there are three `y`s for `request_id = 1` then you will get 3 as output.

Comment: i tried running the exact query and it outputs 1 regardless of how many y's are there .

Comment: Paste the query here which you executed.

Comment: SELECT 
request_id,
(is_requested_resume = 'y' + is_requested_note = 'y' + is_requested_synopsis = 'y' + is_requested_logline = 'y') AS totalYs
FROM requests_tracking
WHERE request_id = 1 ------

And the value of is_requested_resume  & is_requested_logline are equal to 'y' and the value of other two columns are 'n'. So this should ideally output 2 , but instead , it ouputs 1

Comment: Sorry mate. Forgot to enclose each expression inside parentheses. Updated the answer. Please check now

Comment: Thanks a ton bud...appreciate .